# Regular expression to sort out the data

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the list of the following strings:

```
[
    {"name": "somename1-aa"},
    {"name": "somename2-aa"},
    {"name": "somename01-aa"},
    {"name": "somename02-aa"},
    {"name": "somename3-aa"},
    {"name": "somename03-aa"},
    .................
]
```

What is the regular expression to get objects that have only `01` and `02` after `somename`? In my case, the extracted data would be:
`somename01-aa` and `somename02-aa`

Comment: The perfect expression would be to use a `JSON` parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter with a regular expression and test the value.

```js
var array = [{ name: "somename1-aa" }, { name: "somename2-aa" }, { name: "somename01-aa" }, { name: "somename02-aa" }, { name: "somename3-aa" }, { name: "somename03-aa" }],
    result = array.filter(({ name }) => /somename0[12]/.test(name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of stuff would work. You could start with something like

```
(somename(01|02).*(?="))
```

and see if it fits your test cases.

I'd also suggest two resources when working with regex:

https://regex101.com
https://www.regular-expressions.info